# Question regarding the Theorem 8.1.2 (page 191) of Wald’s General Relativity book

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, causality, topology

**Theorem 8.1.2**: *Let $(M, g_{ab})$ be an arbitrary spacetime, and $p\in M$. Then there exists a convex normal neighborhood of $p$, i.e., an open set $U$ with $p\in U$ such that for all $q,r\in U$ there exists a unique geodesic $\gamma$ connecting $q$ and $r$ and staying entirely within $U$. Furthermore, for any such $U$, $I^+(p)|_U$ consists of all points reached by future directed timelike geodesic starting from $p$ and contained within $U$, where $I^+(p)|_U$ denotes the chronological future of $p$ in the spacetime $(U, g_{ab})$. In addition $\dot I^+(p)|_U$ is generated by the future directed null geodesics in $U$ emanating from $p$.*

Now the author says,
If $q\in J^+(p)$ and $\lambda$ is a causal curve beginning at $p$ and ending at $q$ , we can cover $\lambda$ by convex normal neighborhoods, and using the compactness of $\lambda$ (since it is the continuous image of a closed interval), we can extract a finite subcover. If $\lambda$ fail to be a null geodesic in any such neighbourhood, then with the help of theorem 8.1.2 we could deform $\lambda$ into a timelike curve in that neighborhood, and then extend this deformation to the other neighborhoods to obtain a timelike curve from $p$ to $q$.

**Corollary:** *If $ q \in J^+(p)-I^+(p)$ , then any causal curve connecting $p$ to $q$ must be a null geodesic.*

**My first question is**: If the curve is already a causal curve and not null somewhere, will not it be automatically timelike in that region?

**Second Question**: I am not understanding the process of deformation and extending that deformation to other neighborhoods.

**Third Question**: How the above theorem and descriptions imply the corollary?

Comment: I agree with you that this part was confusing. I don't understand what Wald is trying to say. The explanation given by @rhomaios in the other question wasn't any helpful to me either.